# Getting Selenium to Work with Firefox Driver on C# Latest 3.9.0

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I Cannot get Selenium to work with the Firefox Driver on c#.
Chrome works perfectly but not Firefox.

Using:

- Netframework 4.6.1
- Latest version of selenium 3.9.0
- Gecko-driver Downloaded from (manage Nuget packages) 0.19.1
- Using the MSTest.TestAdapater which should work perfectly as it did with Chrome.

I have already set the path variable in Windows.

GeckoDriver is already installed in the Bin folder in sources.

The Firefoxdriverservice does not exist so cannot use that command.

The error im getting is "**threw exception: 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified**"

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace BeatRecaptcha
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        //Go to Google
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.co.uk");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you install everything using NuGet?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you recently upgraded to the latest version of selenium but since Selenium 3.0 you also need to download the geckodriver.exe from the below url as per your system configuration.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Then you can try something like this:

```
//Give the path of the geckodriver.exe    
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64","geckodriver.exe")

//Give the path of the Firefox Browser        
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Install **Selenium.WebDriver.GeckoDriver** via nuget package. (1) **Right click project** and **select manage nuget package**)

[image]

After installation your **references** in the project look like

[image]

After this you will not get the error

Comment: Why is it not published under `selenium` account, and who is `jsakamoto`?

Comment: There are people who have taken initiative and created these drivers. Selenium does not provide these extra things for all browsers. this is github id for that person. he is a microsoft guy only

Answer (score 1):

**Figured it Out Guys.**

It turns out `3.8.0` is only supported in `C#`, not `3.9` which `nuget` automatically installs as the `WebDriver`.
All is working now, you don't even have to specify `driverservice` and point it to the path as it picks it up automatically.